# How to fix this error [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process python

Tags: python, desktop-application

I want to delete the .json file in a desktop application. But the code works only in ubuntu os system, after running windows os system an error appears.

This is the error: `[WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process python`

Here is an example of my full code.

```
  if response.status_code == 200:
       os.unlink('storage/login_data.json')
       Dashboard.destroy(self)
       login.Login()

   else:
       print("Error logging out.")
```

I'm trying this code.

```
 os.remove('storage/login_data.json')
```

Please how do I fix this error?

Comment: What exactly is confusing about the error message? Did you try deleting the file manually?

Comment: The JSON file is not deleting manually.

Comment: Then, it's exactly as the error message tells you: some program (possibly your own) has a lock on the file.